# Is there any way to control subject of Flash message in smpp?

Tags: android, sms, gsm, smpp

I am using smpp protocol to send Flash message. I am doing this to set data_coding to class 0:

```
dataCoding = ((dataCoding | 0x10) & 0xFC)
```

When this gets delivered it appears as:

[image]

Is there any way in smpp protocol using which I can make **Class 0 Message** appearing at top disapper?

Also, these messages get delivered to only a few phones. On some phones, they appear as normal messages. Is there anything else I should use, to make flash messages reliable and more friendly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question on controlling the subject of the message. As Class 0 Flash messages are simply SMS's with just a different message class there is no such thing as a "subject". It is up to the mobile device to handle the immediate display of a flash message.

For the second question this could be for multiple reasons:

1. Mobile device was unable to receive the message due to being "out of range". In most cases mobile operators will adhere to the GSM spec and retry until they get confirmation from the mobile device but this is not always the case.
2. Mobile operator does not allow flash messages to be sent through to it's subscribers
3. Some mobile devices can disable the reception of flash messages
4. Some mobile devices do not have a mechanism to handle flash messages.

Without having more information it's hard to give you a concrete answer on the second part of the question.